# Looping on Scrapy doens't work properly

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a small web crawler with Scrapy.

I wrote a crawler that grabs the URLs of certain links on a certain page, and wrote the links to a csv file. I then wrote another crawler that loops on those links, and downloads some information from the pages directed to from these links.

The loop on the links:

```
cr = csv.reader(open("linksToCrawl.csv","rb"))
start_urls = []
for row in cr:
    start_urls.append("http://www.zap.co.il/rate"+''.join(row[0])[1:len(''.join(row[0]))])
```

If, for example, the URL of the page I'm retrieving information from is:

http://www.zap.co.il/ratemodel.aspx?modelid=835959

then more information can (sometimes) be retrieved from following pages, like:

http://www.zap.co.il/ratemodel.aspx?modelid=835959&pageinfo=2
  ("&pageinfo=2" was added).

Therefore, my rules are:

```
rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor (allow = ("&pageinfo=\d",
    ), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="NumBtn"]',)) 
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),)
```

It seemed to be working fine. However, it seems that the crawler is *only* retrieving information from the pages with the extended URLs (with the "&pageinfo=\d"), and not from the ones without them. How can I fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`parse_start_url()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) method in `CrawlSpider`:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def parse_items(self, response):
        # put your code here
        ...

    parse_start_url = parse_items
```

Comment: Thank you @kev - it works! Although I don't really understand why ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule allows urls with "&pageinfo=\d" . In effect only the pages with matching url will be processed. You need to change the allow parameter for the urls without pageinfo to be processed.

Comment: Thanks @Biswanath. What you say makes sense, but I wrote my code according to this tutorial: [link](http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/) and there it seems like he's got the same issue (the "allow" rule doesn't seem to match the first URL), but somehow it works on his project...